# Code Crashes giving an error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int NUM_ADS=7;
char *ADS[]=
{
    "William: SBM GSOH likes sports,TV,dining",

    "Matt:SWM NS likes art,movies,theater",``

    "Luis:SLM ND likes books,theater,art",

    "Mike:DWM DS likes trucks,sports and bieber"

    "Peter:SAM likes chess,working out and art",

    "Josh:SJM likes sports,movie theatre",

    "Jed:DBM likes theater,books and dining"
};

int sports_no_bieber(char *s)
{
    return strstr(s,"sports")&&!strstr(s,"bieber");
}

int sports_or_workout(char *s)
{
    return strstr(s,"sports")||strstr(s,"working out");
}

int ns_theater(char *s)
{
    return strstr(s,"NS")&&strstr(s,"theater");
}

int arts_theater_or_dining(char *s
{
    return strstr(s,"arts")||strstr(s,"theater")||strstr(s,"dining");
}
```

created a pointer to the functions defined above

```
void find(int(*match)(char*))
{
    int i;

    puts("Search Results:");
    puts("------------------------------------");

    for(i=0;i<NUM_ADS;i++)
    {
        if(match(ADS[i]))
        {
            printf("%s\n",ADS[i]);
        }
    }

    puts("----------------------------------");
}
```

and passed those pointers as parameters to these function i'm getting error segmentation fault

```
int main()
{
    find(sports_no_bieber);
    find(sports_or_workout);
    find(ns_theater);
    find(arts_theater_or_dining);

    return 0;    
}
```

I was creating function pointers and passing them to another function

I ran it through valgrind

Valgrind output

[image: here is the output]

Executable output

[image: output of code]

I'm using ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ADS`, the "Mike" string does *not* have a comma at the end. So, the compiler will [silently] concatenate this with the "Peter" string to create a single string.

This shortens the `ADS` array by one element. The result is that `ADS` will have only 6 elements instead of the 7 that you expect.

Thus, the `for` loop in `find` will go one past the end of the array, causing the segfault

Comment: ahh, I missed that. Thanks for helping now it's working completely fine.